# how to make ajv-cli to consider formats

Tags: json, ajv

I have been experimenting with `ajv-cli` and trying to make it to verify a json scheme that makes use of standard formats like "ipv4" and "host-name".

Despite of having `ajv-formats` installed, when invoked as:

```
ajv --strict=false --validate-formats=true compile -s 2438.schema.json
```

`ajv` complains:

```
unknown format "host-name" ignored in schema at path "#/definitions/ip-address/anyOf/0"
unknown format "host-name" ignored in schema at path "#/definitions/ip-address/anyOf/0"
unknown format "ipv4" ignored in schema at path "#/definitions/ip-address/anyOf/1"
unknown format "ipv4" ignored in schema at path "#/definitions/ip-address/anyOf/1"
unknown format "ipv6" ignored in schema at path "#/definitions/ip-address/anyOf/2"
unknown format "ipv6" ignored in schema at path "#/definitions/ip-address/anyOf/2"
```

How do I make `ajv-cli` to accept standard formats? Am I missing something obvious?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 12):

I faced the same situation today, trying to get acquainted with a [specific json schema](https://github.com/RDA-DMP-Common/RDA-DMP-Common-Standard/tree/master/examples/JSON/JSON-schema). I searched for a validation tool, and found `ajv-cli`.

```
> npm install ajv-cli
> npx ajv validate -s maDMP-schema-1.1.json -d foo.json
schema maDMP-schema-1.1.json is invalid
error: unknown format "email" ignored in schema at path "#/properties/dmp/properties/contact/properties/mbox"
```

It took me a while before I discovered the [-c option](https://github.com/ajv-validator/ajv-cli#-c---custom-keywordsformats-definitions):

```
> npm install ajv-formats
> npx ajv validate -s maDMP-schema-1.1.json -d foo.json -c ajv-formats
foo.json valid
```

Hope it's the right way to do it!

Comment: Yes, using the '-c ajv-formats' flag after installing ajv-formats via npm worked perfectly